# nutch prevent indexing parent url

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I am using nutch-1.15 with elasticsearch. I want to crawl all the links present in the parent url and index them. But I dont want to index the parent url.

```
Ex: 
Parent url : http://someLink.com/cgi-bin/parent.cgi
                 http://somelink.com/cgi-bin/link1
                 http://somelink.com/cgi-bin/link2
                 http://somelink.com/cgi-bin/link3
```

I want to index only urls like link1,link2,link3 ... but not the parent url http://someLink.com/cgi-bin/parent.cgi

How can this be done?

Comment: For correct understanding: shall the parent URL be crawled to extract the links? Or are the links already known?

Comment: links are not known already.It should crawl parent url and extract the links to crawl and index them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 +^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?somelink\.[a-zA-Z0-9.\S]+\/cgi-bin\/.*
```

into conf/regex-urlfilter, the previous command allows you to allow the following links

```
<http://somelink.com/cgi-bin/link1>
<http://somelink.com/cgi-bin/link2>
<http://somelink.com/cgi-bin/link3> 
<http://somelink.com/cgi-bin/>
```

If you place a restriction before it, it should work

Into conf/regex-urlfilter

```
-^http:\/\/somelink.com\/cgi-bin\/parent.cgi
+^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?somelink\.[a-zA-Z0-9.\S]+\/cgi-bin\/.*
-^.`
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin "index-jexl-filter" allows to exclude documents from getting indexed but they're still crawled, parsed and outlinks are followed.

1. activate the plugin by adding it to the property "plugin.includes"
2. define a [Jexl expression](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html) in the property "index.jexl.filter" which evaluates to false for the parent page. In addition to the URL itself, also HTTP status, title and many more variables are available in the Jexl context. In doubt, have a look at the [JexlIndexingFilter](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/index-jexl-filter/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/jexl/JexlIndexingFilter.java) class.

You can easily test the expression:

```
% bin/nutch indexchecker \
  -Dplugin.includes='protocol-okhttp|parse-html|index-(basic|jexl-filter)' \
  -Dindex.jexl.filter=' url != "http://localhost/" ' http://localhost/
fetching: http://localhost/
...
Document discarded by indexing filter
```

Other URLs are indexed, i.e., the indexed fields are shown:

```
% bin/nutch indexchecker \
  -Dplugin.includes='protocol-okhttp|parse-html|index-(basic|jexl-filter)' \
  -Dindex.jexl.filter=' url != "http://localhost/" ' http://localhost/index.html
fetching: http://localhost/index.html
...
title : Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page: It works
url :   http://localhost/index.html
...
```